# Is it possible to globally define links to use a specific component?

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

I'm currently trying to use `Nav` with `react-router`. The default behavior reloads the page, so I'm trying to use the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`.

It's quite difficult to preserve the default styling when overriding `linkAs`.

Is there any global way to override link navigation behavior?
Like defining a global link render function, which I can then set to render the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible!

2 things are required:

1. Make a wrapper component that translates the Nav API to react-router-dom links.
2. Specify the `linkAs` prop to the `Nav` component.

### Wrapper component

This is a simple component that creates a react-router-dom link while using styles from Fabric:

```jsx
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const LinkTo = props => {
  return (
    <Link to={props.href} className={props.className} style={props.style}>
      {props.children}
    </Link>
  );
};
```

### Specify component for use in Nav

```jsx
 <Nav groups={links} linkAs={LinkTo} />
```

Have also created a full working example at https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-wozniak-y10tr?file=/src/index.tsx:605-644